# Images are invisible in map activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I want the page to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVbjQ.png

The images of the home and profile button are shown at the android studio preview But not shown as i run the app.Please help me figure out why.

activity_accident.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/BtnHome"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/homegrey" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/BtnLogOut"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/head"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/map"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:text="Please Choose a User From The Map to Contact With:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        tools:context="info.androidhive.RoadsideAssistance.Accident"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is what it looks like when i run the app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkJ7U.png

Comment: Can you post an image of what is shown when you run the app?

Comment: Does your map view overlapping with your images?

Comment: i edited and added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You have used srcCompat to load vector drawable.

**app:srcCompat**

Include `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary` in you gradle.

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

Hope it helps:)